# Python3 strptime from ISO8601 with timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

How to convert string in ISO8601 time format to python3 datetime.
Here is my time:

```js
2017-03-03T11:30:00+04:00
```

And the way I try:

```js
datetime.strptime(appointment['datetime'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

The problem here, is that I don't know how to represent +4:00 timezone in format parameter of .strptime method.

Comment: please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-to-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date . I think this will be helpful parser class of dateutil library of python will do fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that [`%z`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) in python datetime doesn't include a colon:

> **%z**:   UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM (empty string if the object is naive) e.g. +0000, -0400, +1030

However, the date string in the example does have a colon e.g. `+04:00`. Just by not including that colon you can parse the date.

```
>>> s = "2017-03-03T11:30:00+04:00"
>>> datetime.strptime(s[:len(s)-3] + s[len(s)-2:], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 3, 11, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 14400)))
```

---

I would suggest that you use this powerful library [`python-dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html):

```
>>> from dateutil import parser
>>> parser.parse("2017-03-03T11:30:00+04:00")
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 3, 11, 30, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 14400))
```

Comment: `dateutil.parser` is too wide, such as `parse("Thu, 25 Sep 2003 10:49:41 -0300")` can also work. How to limit the format of the time only to ISO-8601 with timezone？